# What is the best way to terminate thread that calls ReadByte method

Tags: c#, multithreading, networking

I have an SslStream object that calls ReadByte method in the infinite loop running in the separate thread:

```
private String GetResponse()
{
    var serverResponse = new StringBuilder();

    while (true)
    {
        int byteFromStream = _sslStream.ReadByte();
        if (byteFromStream != -1)
        {
            serverResponse.Append((char)byteFromStream);

            try
            {
                JContainer.Parse(serverResponse.ToString());
                break;
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }

    return serverResponse.ToString();
}
```

What is the best way to terminate such thread? I can't set any timeout followed by the interruption point because it is really unknown how long should I wait for the next data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can set a timeout, just loop back if a flag isn't set to exit.

Comment: Unclear. What should be the conditions(s) to terminate?

Comment: @Henk Holterman For example, I need to terminate this thread if the Disconnect method was called or in the Dispose method and destructor

Comment: Just close the stream.  You'll get an ObjectDisposedException, be sure to catch it and get out quick.

Comment: @Hans Passant Is it safe to call Close method from the other thread while ReadByte is running?

Comment: You cannot get a warranty here with this little documentation.  I have no idea what that _sslStream might be.  Sure it is safe.  If it is not then you'll find out.

Comment: @Hans Passant _sslStream is the object of SslStream class

Comment: I don't know if it's safe or not to call `Read` and `Close` at the same time. Technically I suppose it isn't since the documentation says instance methods are not thread-safe. However, you could change your code to use `BeginRead` instead of `Read`. If you then called `Close` it would not be executing at the same time as `BeginRead` (since that call will return immediately). Just make sure you really don't call them at the same time. Use a `lock` or something.

Comment: @BrianGideon - Read or BeginRead does not really make a difference. You can still interrupt the reading process at any point.

Answer (score 0):

Set the thread's `IsBackground` property to `true`.